# JavaScript inheritance (setting the prototype internal) fails

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I tried to set the prototype property inside the constructor-function, but it doesn't work, but why? If I set the property external, everything works. Thanks!

```
var a=function(){
    this.x=1;
}

var b=function(){
    this.prototype=new a();

    this.getX=function(){
        return this.x;
    }
}

alert(b.prototype);

var test=new b();
alert(test.getX());
```

Answer (score 0):

Whats happening is you are creating a public property for each instance of "b" called 'prototype'. Not the actual prototype object to inherit from.

```
var a=function(){
  this.x=1;
}

var b=function(){

this.getX=function(){
    return this.x;
 }
}

// every new instance of b will inherit 'x: 1'
b.prototype = new a();

console.log(b.prototype);

var test=new b();
console.log(test.getX());
```

check out this link for more info on 
[Prototypal inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Comment: ok, i think i have understood it. So the prototype property is only relevant for the constructor, not for the instance. Thank you